# VPN-сервер за NAT на OpenWRT(SuperWRT)

Tags: сеть, vpn, openwrt

Есть удалёнынй офис, в офисе роутер OpenWRT(SuperWRT) с настроеным VPN. Роутер подключен к интернету который неизвесно как через неизвесное количество роутеров и NAT'ов раздается арендодателем.
Как подключится к локальной сети офиса по VPN? Может стоит заюзать сервер на Ubuntu?
*TeamViewer не предлагать.*

Comment: А чем не подходит TeamViewer, если не секрет?

Comment: Тем что на OpenWRT не встанет :), а городить из сервера шлюз не охота. Сервер это сервер, шлюз это шлюз. Хотя вариантов может быть много, я предпочитаю лаконичные и без излишеств.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если у офиса нет внешнего IP то **к** офису не как. Однако вы можете использовать некий внешний сервер (назовем его Сервер) с OpenVPN-сервером и внешним IP который будет играть роль точки входа. То есть офисный роутер будет подключаться по OpenVPN к Серверу и вы по OpenVPN к серверу. И вуаля вы имеет доступ к локальной сети офиса.

В прочем TeamViewer или нормальный провайдер в офисе возможно будет дешевле.

**UPD:** Вот как-то так у вас должно внешние выглядеть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И так работать изнутри:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поподробнее можно? Именно такой вариант и хочу реализовать.

Comment: Вы спросите по конкретнее и будет вам поподробнее. Про что вам рассказать? Как арендовать VPS? Как поднять на нем Linux? Я же не знаю что вы умеете а что нет.

Comment: @kyb, подробнее будет уже только *настройка openvpn*. по которой есть огромное количество примеров, документации, рассказов, повестей и романов.

Comment: Допустим есть сервер на котором настроен VPN-сервер с белым IP. Достаточно подключить к нему офисный OpenWRT и желаемых клиентов и всё заработает? Мне бы понять архитектуру, детали настройки не проблема.

Comment: Именно. Плюс нужно будет настроить на VPN-сервере пуш маршрутов до офисных компов. У вас получиться новая VPN-сеть из которой будет доступ к офисным машинам.